# Using Standard Asset RBFP Controller for Universal Windows Platform

Tags: unity, universal-windows

I was using the rigidbodyfirstperson controller, and it stopped working when I changed the build settings to UWP. Any body know the reason for this or how to solve it? Thanks...

Rik

Comment: Hey man, sadly, my magic crystal ball broke. Would you mind providing us with more information?
- Are there any errors?
- Is it a standard component or is a 3rd party plugin with the same name?

Comment: It's the standard asset first person character prefab you can import from the asset menu. If you go to build settings, universal windows platform is second setting, it's what you have to use if you use windows mixed reality or xbox or any microsoft product. I get no errors when I run it, the mouse and keyboard  controls just stop working

Comment: Would you mind checking, whether you actually receive any input events? I.e. create a new component, add it to the camera, and have it print all input to the console.
This way we can exclude at least one reason.